# output overload using template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

So I'm trying to overload the output operator using templates, but I keep running into two errors. They are:

Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition

and

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '<'

```
template <typename E> class SLinkedList; //forward declaration

template <typename E>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const SLinkedList<E>& v); //forward declaration

template <typename E> 
class SLinkedList {
public:

template <typename E>
friend ostream& operator<< <E>(ostream& out, const SLinkedList<E>& v);
};

template <typename E>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, E const SLinkedLst<E>& v) {
while (v->next != NULL) {
    out << v->elem;
    v->next;
}

return out;
}
```

Comment: Your class is missing a trailing `;`.

Comment: Must have missed it when I copy and pasted. I fixed it though.

Comment: Right. What else did your clipboard change?

Comment: what is `E const SLinkedLst<E>& v` ?

Comment: Syntax copied from my book, I'm pretty lost when it come to overloading.

Comment: Don't use `typename E` twice

Answer (score 1):

`<E>` is not needed in

```
friend ostream& operator<< <E>(ostream& out, const SLinkedList<E>& v);
```

Just get rid of it and it should compile.

You are also missing a `;` at the end of you class.  In C++ a `class` and `struct` declaration must end with a `;`

You have an extra `E` in

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, E const SLinkedLst<E>& v) {
                                   ^ what is this doing here?
```

You are also missing a `;` at then end of

```
v->next
```

You are also using the same template name in

```
template <typename E> 
class SLinkedList {
public:

template <typename E>
friend ostream& operator<< <E>(ostream& out, const SLinkedList<E>& v);
};
```

Which `E` is the function referring too?  You will need to change it to some other name.

Comment: Whenever I remove the extra E I get a missing type specifier error.

Comment: @RichardRasmussen You really need to supply a [mcve] then

Comment: Solved the problem. I was missing an "i" in SLinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Try that instead

```
template <typename E> 
class SLinkedList {
public:
template <typename T>
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const SLinkedList<T>& v);
};

template <typename E>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const SLinkedList<E>& v) {
while (v->next != NULL) {
    out << v->elem;
    v->next;
}

  return out;
}
```